# How can I install the latest version of jsPDF using yarn?

Tags: yarnpkg, jspdf

The current stable release is 1.5.3 of [jsPDF](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jspdf) but it's nearly 2 years old.

The master branch is already on 2.1.1. The fix I need is in a patch just after 1.5.3.

How can I use yarn to install [this version](https://github.com/MrRio/jsPDF)?

Currently my `package.json` file looks like this:

```json
"dependencies": {
    "jspdf: "^1.5.3",
    "jspdf-autotable": "^3.3.2"

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify the version using a git url. For GitHub repos, you can use the short version `user/repo#<commit-ish>`, where `commit-ish` is a commit hash, branch, or tag.

Using the latest commit on the master branch as an example:

```
"dependencies": {
    "jspdf: "MrRio/jsPDF#2c5e6c7",
    "jspdf-autotable": "^3.3.2"

}
```

This will work with both Yarn and NPM.

NPM docs: https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json#git-urls-as-dependencies